# Store hyperlink of a file using relative path

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have created a hyperlink that connects to the files which exist in the same directory (or subdirectory) as the Excel file. How do I point to the file without setting the full path? The reason I don't want to give the full path is that if I moved the directory which contains other files and the Excel file to a different location, the hyperlinks shouldn't break.

I tried the option below, but the hyperlink only works if I don't move the files.

[image]

I want to assign the hyperlink an address like `Example\IndexUsage_notes.txt` instead of the full path `D:\SCRIPTS\ADMIN_SCRIPTS\Example\IndexUsage_notes.txt`

Comment: Putting in Example\IndexUsage_notes.txt doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 2):

After searching online, I found this articles to be useful:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/631-excel-file-location.html

This shows you how to get the file path of your workbook and how to isolate the main directory without using Macros.

Then you can insert your main file directory, sub-directory, and filename into the HYPERLINK function.

You can add text to the main directory using TEXT($B$1,0)&TEXT($B$2,0)&......

Dynamic Hyperlink Spreadsheet.png

[image: Dynamic Hyperlink Spreadsheet.png]

Once the sub-directories are created and files are in place, you may not be able to move them easily without changing the sub-directory name manually within the spreadsheet or using Macros.